# Recursively Read Files Spark wholeTextFiles

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark

I have a directory in an azure data lake that has the following path:

'adl://home/../psgdata/clusters/iptiqadata-prod-cluster-eus2-01/psgdata/mib'

Within this directory there are a number of other directories (50) that have the format 20190404.

The directory 'adl://home/../psgdata/clusters/iptiqadata-prod-cluster-eus2-01/psgdata/mib/20180404' contains 100 or so xml files which I am working with.

I can create an rdd for each of the sub-folders which works fine, but ideally I want to pass only the top path, and have spark recursively find the files. I have read other SO posts and tried using a wildcard thus:

```
pathWild = 'adl://home/../psgdata/clusters/iptiqadata-prod-cluster-eus2-01/psgdata/mib/*'
rdd = sc.wholeTextFiles(pathWild)
rdd.count()
```

But it just freezes and does nothing at all, seems to completely destroy the kernel. I am working in Jupyter on Spark 2.x. New to spark. Thanks!

Comment: Any specific reason to use `wholeTextFiles` and not `sc.textFile` with wildcard?

Comment: Because there are newlines in the xml files so textFile is reading each line as a row which is not desired. Is there some reason not to use wholeTextFiles? Is there some way to make textFile ignore the newline?

Comment: How large are the xml files? `wholeTextFiles` doesn't work well with large files. You can also use the databricks-xml package to create dataframes out of xml files.

Comment: They are small individually, 150kb or so. I want to use the databrick package but I am sitting behind a highly regulated system where I cannot install new packages and it takes some weeks for packages to be approved and installed, hence why i am trying to hack around.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

```
pathWild = 'adl://home/../psgdata/clusters/iptiqadata-prod-cluster-eus2-01/psgdata/mib/*/*'
```

Comment: Thank you for the suggestion, but it does not seem to work. Its very odd, it does not throw and error, but the operation simply never completes. There are only 6000 xml files in the entire directory, so size should not be the issue. I am confused.